# Сайт отображение местоположения android устройств в реальном времени

Tags: php, python, openstreetmap

У меня есть простое приложение на андроид, которое, например, каждую минуту отправляет координаты местоположения на сервер (простой php или python сайт, но желательно на питоне). Там я их принимаю, и чисто ради интереса записываю в базу. Все вроде работает.

Теперь хочу сделать на сайте карту, на которой бы в реальном времени было видно расположение андроид устройства. Важно чтобы расположение обновлялось в реальном времени

Примером может быть life360 или этот сайт https://www.locationof.com/demo/map/. Но мне для начала не нужен никакой доп. функционал.
Нашел хорошую библиотеку Leaflet. Но самому не получается все это сделать на практике(

Поделитесь опытом, возможно даже каким то кодом.Всем заранее спасибо